# Can I submit my old highscores online without having to beat them again?

Tags: cubemen

I just noticed that my "best score" on one of the levels in Cubemen is higher than the current global highscore.  But when I check the leaderboard, I'm not at the top, so I must not have submitted the score after completing the level.

Is there anyway to submit my old high-score without having to play the level again and get a higher one?

[image: GLobal high score]

Comment: Do you know for a fact that the submission failed and it's not merely because the leaderboard hasn't updated right away? Have you beaten other levels and had the global leaderboard update immediately?

Comment: @FAE I last played this game more than a week ago, and I had 'auto-save scores' turned off because I don't like anything using my connection without asking.  I probably just didn't bother to submit my score, which I think I've done on other levels too.

Comment: Ah okay, that makes a bit more sense, thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

Since you had the auto submit turned off I would highly doubt that they would let you submit your own score.  Most games that do global high scores based on a local game will not allow you to submit a high score that was not done through their system.  It is unfortunate, but there are ways to manipulate your scores on your local so you could make it appear that you scored higher than you actually did.